# How to make a checklist with horizontal line connecting text to checkboxes?

Tags: lists, line, box

With checklists, it can be hard to see what text corresponds to what checkbox. I'd like to have a horizontal line "connecting" the text to the boxes so that I can follow the text with my eyes to the corresponding box.

The following code is an attempt at doing that (I didn't write this myself, I honestly don't remember where I got it from, but I've been trying to adapt it to my purposes), which doesn't work:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[text={16cm,24cm}]{geometry}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2in}
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft #1]%
{\raggedright #1}}

\newenvironment{checklist}{%
  \begin{list}{}{}
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand\item{\olditem -- \marginpar{$\framebox(15,15){}$ $\framebox(15,15){}$} }
  \newcommand\itemline{\olditem -- \marginpar{\rule[-0.5ex]{0.5\marginparwidth}{0.4pt} $\framebox(15,15){}$ $\framebox(15,15){}$}}
}{%
  \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{checklist}
    \item Item1
%   \itemline Item2
\end{checklist}

\end{document}
```

In this code, the "item" command creates just text and a pair of checkboxes at the end.

The "itemline" command is supposed to do the same, but also add the aforementioned horizontal line.

Why doesn't this work as intended? I've been trying to fiddle with it but I'm struggling with making it working.

Comment: Please add a screenshot next time. Saves a lot of work for all of us ...

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, will do.

Comment: The square brackets of `\rule` conflict with the optional argument of your redefinition of `\marginpar`. Add braces in the optional argument of `\oldmarginpar`, like `\raggedleft{#1}`. However, I don't think this is the best approach. You might get better answers if you explained what the output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion of `\itemline` involves

```
\marginpar{\rule[-0.5ex]{0.5\marginparwidth}{0.4pt} ...}
```

and with your redefinition of `\marginpar` this becomes

```
\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft \rule[-0.5ex]{0.5\marginparwidth}{0.4pt} ...]{\raggedright \rule[-0.5ex]{0.5\marginparwidth}{0.4pt} ...}
% from here-->                        <--to here
```

The problem is now that the scanning of the optional argument for `\oldmarginpar` collects everything up to the first `]`, and so the optional argument is now

```
\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft \rule[-0.5ex
```

Chaos ensues. You might hide the brackets of `\rule` by putting appropriate braces, but I would simply use a completely different code. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[text={16cm,24cm}]{geometry}

\newenvironment{checklist}{%
   \let\olditem=\item
   \def\item{\olditem\def\item{\addlineandboxes\olditem}}%
   \list{--}{}%
}{%
  \addlineandboxes\endlist
}
\newcommand*{\mycheckbox}{\hbox{\vrule\vbox{\hrule width2ex \kern2ex\hrule}\vrule}}
\newcommand*{\addlineandboxes}{\hrulefill\rlap{\space\mycheckbox\space\mycheckbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{checklist}
   \item Item1
   \item Item2 long text such that it takes more than one line long text such that it takes more than one line
   \item Item3
\end{checklist}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Adjust the parameters as you like.

(By the way: `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`?? I seriously doubt you want *that*. And loading `babel` without language isn't entirely useful either.)

Comment: Wow, that works, thanks. Any way to make that line centered on the middle (vertically) instead of being more like a long underscore?